# Bing Maps Javascript SDK returns different values for state abbreviations

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Using the latest version (6.3) of the Bing Maps AJAX Control I'm having the following problem: I get different lat/lon results for the map center if I do a VEMap.Find() for a city/state using the state abbreviation vs the state's full name.

Example:

```
Lehi, UT: 40.38966, -111.847473 
Lehi, Utah: 40.1952667, -111.795029
```

The difference is significant enough to really wreck the results (using "Utah" puts the center point in the middle of a large lake).

I'm mostly wondering if there is a proper fix for this other than having to convert all state names to abbreviations. So far We've only experienced problems with spelled out state names (only about 5% of the time) but wee haven't done enough testing to say it won't happen with abbreviations on other cities. It's a pin because we allow users to input addresses and they usually use an abbreviation for the state name.